# How to replace IP addresses represented in the page as text with its IP location (as "Country, Region, City" for example)

Tags: javascript, ajax, location, ip

I'm trying to write Opera user JS for replacing IP addresses represented in the page as text with its IP location.  After googling for a while I found a service which provides exactly the information I needed.

This service for a HTTP query returns the header of the page with meta containing the needed info.
As example, this  query: `http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=142.34.25.111`
(see source of the page)
In the browser this request works fine.
I tried to get this text (as XML) via AJAX, but encountered an error `ReferenceError: Security violation` at line `xmlhttp.send();`.

So, my questions is:
 - Is existing any practice to obtain IP location from IP address via JS (without any fee || registration)
 - How I can to replace some content of the one page to modified content of the another page via JS?

PS. I am very new in JS programming.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function loadXMLDoc()
  {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
          //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          var x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.documentElement;
          var i, s, xx;
          s = '';
          for (i=0; i < x.length; i++)
          {
            xx = x[i].documentElement;
            if (xx.attributes[0] == 'country') s = s + xx.attributes[1].textContent;
            if (xx.attributes[0] == 'region') s = s + ', ' + xx.attributes[1].textContent;
            if (xx.attributes[0] == 'city') s = s + ', ' + xx.attributes[1].textContent;
          }
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = s;
        }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=142.34.25.111",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Test page included.

Ok, Thanks a lot to all!
May be my question is not clear enough.
Lets try again (I told this to myself):
I need JS function like `IPAddress2IPLocation(InIPAddress)` which returns IP location  in format `Country, Region, City` using passed parameter.

Is anybody know answer for my question?
At this time (3:50 AM here) I approved for any suggestions :)
But, in any case, it is not extremely bout my life - it is just interesting about JS.

Comment: why don't you put the source code so we can see if there's an error? Apparently you already found a way to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript security! Fear not, there are ways to work around the same origin policy.

[Getting around same origin policy in javascript without server side scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceError: Security violation` is not asking you to pay a fee. You are doing [Cross-site Scripting](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) which is a security violation on most browsers.

You can avoid this error using a proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to accessing another domain from Ajax. For security reasons, only requests to the same domain name can be made.

The code http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspxcode_net.aspx describes the basics for building ip to location translation.