# Control a frame from container page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a web page that contains two textboxes and a button. I can't control this page by adding any thing to it, or changing any thing in it.

I want to (in some way) write some text in the first textbox when the page loads, without pressing the button.

I want to put the page in a frame and then control it from the container page

I know that I have to use jquery but I need a sample that explain that or to tell me how to do what I want

For example, if I have the file "a.htm":

The content of "a.htm":

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="f.htm" />
```

and the content of "f.htm" is:

```
<input type="textbox" id="tbx1" />
<input type="textbox" id="tbx2" />
<input type="submit" id="okbtn" value="ok"/>
```

For example, when the page "a.htm" loads, I want the textbox ("tbx1" for example) in the page "f.htm", (contained in the frame "frame1") to be filled by some text.

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I start on this answer, it's worth explaining that you **cannot use JavaScript alone to manipulate a frame which serves content from a separate domain***. In other words, if your page, a.htm, is on your domain (e.g. http://yourdomain.com/a.htm), and f.htm is on another domain (e.g. http://someothersite.com/f.htm), then JS will **not** be able to access anything inside the iframe.

**There are techniques available to do this, but as a rule of thumb they cause more trouble than good.*

However, if it's all on the same domain you should have no trouble. In `a.htm`, to access the iframe, you could use the following jQuery snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var iframe = $('#frame1').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('#tbx1').val('Text in a box!');
  });
});
```

So, your `a.htm` could look like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        var iframe = $('#frame1').load(function() {
          $(this).contents().find('#tbx1').val('Text in a box!');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="frame1" src="f.htm" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. What do you mean by 'a frame contained in the page'?

Comment: thank you very much it was useful .... but are there any way to control frame from a separate domain !!????

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts/2067240#2067240) - it's pretty much perfect