# Receive serialized in php data by using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deserialization

I have a php script, which return serialized in php data. And I try to receive this data by using $.ajax() method from jQuery 1.7. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q69sW/8/) is the example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://input.name/get.php?do=lookup' + '&domain=twittorama&tlds=.ru,.com,.net,.comf.ru',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: 'false',
    complete: function(res) {
        alert('COMPLETE() done');
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

In console I see only

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
```

So, what I do wrong? Could you help me please?

**UPD**

Interesting notice: if I use JSONP dataType request can receive data, but can't process it.
[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/q69sW/12/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://input.name/get.php?do=lookup',
    data: 'domain=twittorama&tlds=.ru,.com,.net,.comf.ru',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Data: "+data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: "+textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `complete:` use `success:` then `res` will be the returned data from your ajax request.

Remember to use `error:` as well incase there is an error with you call, as it seems that there might be in your console output.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://input.name/get.php?do=lookup',
    data: 'domain=twittorama&tlds=.ru,.com,.net,.comf.ru',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Data: "+data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: "+textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q69sW/11/ - it's the code with error processing - it doesn't show any details of error

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably fine, but you're trying to violate the [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). Basically, if your site is `http://aaa.com/`, you cannot make AJAX called to `http://bbb.com/`.

There are a few ways around it:

- [Getting around same origin policy in javascript without server side scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts)

But most of them require that both sides play nice.

Comment: but if it's the problem - why I don't receive any detailed error message from jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'r expecting, but *I* do see the following error message in my JS console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://input.name/get.php?do=lookup&domain=twittorama&tlds=.ru,.com,.net,.comf.ru. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: I've updated my answer - in dataType='jsonp' case request can receive the data...

Comment: Because it's not JSON. That's what I meant by both sides "playing nice".

Comment: I just want to say that it's not a policy problem if I see the data in console. So, I don't understand why I can't see the data and receive an error when I use 'text' dataType...

Comment: You can't the see data when using `text` because of the same origin policy. You can't use the data using `jsonp` because the data is not JSON. They're two completely different issues.

Comment: so, it means that for 'jsonp' case origin policy is right, but for 'text' case it's not right. I always think that ways to get data by using different data types are the same - but processing of this data is unique for each case. this fact embarrass me.

Answer (score 1):

The response is the second parameter of complete function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://input.name/get.php?do=lookup' + '&domain=twittorama&tlds=.ru,.com,.net,.comf.ru',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: 'false',
    complete: function(res,response) {
        alert('COMPLETE() done');
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You should also consider using JSON, not php serialized data

Comment: here is some problem - input.name is a service site, which provide only php-serialized data

Comment: I see this function. But before process this data, I should get it from remote host. I try to use your code - it logs "error" in console.

Comment: try using your browser console for debugging this. You should have more information about this request in firebug plugin (firefox) or developer console (chrome) - there are also detailed information about each ajax request

Comment: propably it's the same origin policy violation, but everything about this should be visible in developer console and debug info there

Comment: if I use console from Chrome and if I use 'jsonp' dataType I can see my data in it. but jquery can't process it right - because it's not a json data. so, it means that request can receive data in this case. but can't receive it, when using 'text' dataType. it's confusing me.