# Ajax cross domain on same machine but different port

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

We have a set of api that we're calling from the same machine, the address is `mycompany.com:8080` for the server and `mycompany.com` for the ajax.html file.

How can we avoid the cross domain policy?

Anyway to do this with some proxy configuration?

**please, no JSONP!**

Thanks!

Comment: what backend language are you using ?

Comment: Include a response Header with these values "Access-Control-Allow-Origin : mycompany.com" on the server, it shall allow to access the resource.

Comment: I would like to avoid any modification of the backend. It's java by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting around same origin policy in javascript without server side scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts) and a gazillian others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two or more documents can be considered in same domain origin, if they have on 
 - Same Host
 - Same Port
 - Same Protocol.
In your case port is different so you can not put ajax query directly. Instead you need to specify following header in response.

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mycompany.com
```

For more info, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 2):

You ask if this can be done with a proxy configuration, and of course that's one simple solution, just have the main server proxy requests to the AJAX server.  It's usually simple to set up.  But the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) means that you won't be able to do this with a pure client-side solution.