# Retrieving IFrame content using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have already received javascript code from this very website.

```
alert(window.frames['sc_frame'].document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);
```

or

```
alert(window.frames['sc_frame'].document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);
```

The problem is I am having this error.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx from frame with URL http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluate
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
arguments: Array[2]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "non_object_property_call"
__proto__: Error
```

I also understand the cause as my `IFrame` is calling to another domain.

```
<iframe id="sc_frame" src="http://example1.com"></iframe>
```

I use the above code from `http://example.com`.

My question would be whether there is a workaround for this. either using javascript or any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly communicate with other elements in the body across domains (/ports/protocols) due to security constraints.  Not only can't you access the target document source, you can't access the objects and events either.

What you *can* do, is use frameworks for sending messages across domains via a proxy.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts) talks about that.

Comment: So, according to that answer, we need to write something in `example1.com` to pass the info back to `example.com`? i dun really get what that means.. Sry

Comment: What I was talking about is communication between two iframes which come from different domains, not server to server communication (which is also possible of course but not what you were asking).  What the frameworks I was talking about let you do is send a message from iframe in example1.com to a proxy server (yourproxy.com), and then the iframe from example.com can communicate with yourproxy.com and ask "do i have any messages from the example1.com iframe?".  This way the two iframes can communicate but not directly between themselves.