# Ajax request using img tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have a problem where I want to communicate on my own server between port 80 and port 8080 using an ajax request. I am aware of CORS and cross domain request origin policy and [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067029/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-javascript-without-server-side-scripts) solution to this problem.

Out of curiosity I want to know if and how this can be done. if the requested information is called as a `<img>` tag with an SRC of the URL that needs to be called and the returned content is somehow parsed from the data that is recieved --

is this possible? if not, why and if yes how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the same domain, this is possible with a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement): you draw the image to a canvas with `canvas.drawImage`, and then use `canvas.toDataURL` or `canvas.toBlob` to get the data on the canvas.

In a cross-domain situation, `toDataURL` and `toBlob` will be blocked if the canvas has been ["tainted" with a cross-domain image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image). To overcome this restriction, you must:

1. Serve the image with CORS headers, *and*
2. Set the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin) of the `<img>` (to either "`anonymous`" or "`use-credentials`", depending on whether the fetch should be done with cookies or not).

Answer (score 0):

No. While there are APIs to access image data (although I think they are all related to bitmaps loaded onto `<canvas>` rather than `<img>`), you can't access the data from a different origin because the Same Origin Policy still applies.